# Angular/javascript select element - filter by string not only on the first letter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

In Angular (and in html), when faced with a select element the user can type a letter and the list will jump to the first entry with that letter. So for example:

With focus on the ddl, pressing 'f' on your keyboard jumps to the first 'foo'.
But what if I have a massive list and want to find 'man' in foomanchu?

```html
<select>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>fun</option>
  <option>fuu</option>
  <option>fuuman</option>
  <option>fuumanchu</option>
  <option>zoo</option>
</select>
```

I want to retain the original behavior of being able to jump through the alphabet, but need to add a kind of grep functionality to it.

I cannot replace the ddl `<select>` with a normal search/filter because:

- the list is very long
- users sometimes know what to search, other times need to scroll alphabetically to find the right item in the list (company names) so the list must also be visible in its entirety.

Is there a way to add string search to a `<select>` ?

Comment: would make a lot better user experience to use a more friendly UI than `<select>` for the very reason you say you can't use it.... `the list is very long`. Nothing worse than clicking on a `<select>` and seeing 1000 choices. That being said you can filter `ng-options`

Comment: I think the select works fine with alphabetical skipping, I was suggesting that a search that displays results is sub-optimal as there can be a lot of results and there isn't space in the gui (plus the client/spec decides it).  ng-options will only allow me to filter the list pre-load, but I want the user to be able to do a partial string search on the full list, preferably without adding any gui elements.